# How Can I see debug perspective in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to know how to see result of variables without dump to console. Thanks to all.

Comment: Wndow->Open Perspective...->Debug

Comment: A Google search should be more than sufficient to answer this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must start your program in debug mode (F11 instead of Ctrl-F11 on Windows).

If Eclipse does not automatically switch to the Debug perspective, you can locate it manually in the Window entry on the menu bar or by clicking the Choose Perspective button (a button with a plus on it) in the upper right corner of the Eclipse window under the menu bar line.

EDIT: There is a quick tutorial on how to do this in Eclipse (on Linux, but it should be very similar on other platforms) at http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Comment: I opened debug, but I do not see any variables and theirs values.

Comment: You will not see any unless you put a break point somewhere in your code and the debugger breaks.  Otherwise, what would you be looking at?  Thousands of variables changing so fast you couldn't see them anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Open the Debug Perspective and click on the Variables View.